# Макрос для нахождения минимального

Tags: c++, макрос

Как написать макрос для нахождения наименьшего из трёх элементов?

Comment: Будьте добры, переведите вопрос - согласно правилам - на русский...

Comment: Макросы, ИМХО, это для Си, так как в С++ есть более полезные встроенные функции, так как с макросами слишком много проблем.

Answer (score 6):

Примерно так:

```
#define MIN(a,b,c)  (((a) < (b))? (((a) < (c))? (a) : (c)) : (((b) < (c))? (b) : (c)))
```

Comment: А за что минус? Ответ по идее правильный, ну и вопрос не такой уж бесполезный.

Comment: @VladD может не понравились тернарные операторы но в условие не обозначено, что их нельзя использовать